# With functional programming, using fplus: error when converting vector<vector<string>> to vector<vector<int>>

Tags: c++, vector, functional-programming

I am practicing functional programming, using the fplus library (https://github.com/Dobiasd/FunctionalPlus).

The given vector of vectors of strings

```
const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> singleGradeStatisticPairsAsStr = { {"10", "1"}, {"20", "2"}, {"30", "3"} };
```

is supposed to be converted to a vector of vector of ints.

Using iterative style this could be implemented as

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> singleGradeStatisticPairs;
for (auto singleGradeStatisticPair : singleGradeStatisticPairsAsStr) {
    std::vector<int> singleGradeStatisticPairAsInt;
    for (auto element : singleGradeStatisticPair) {
        singleGradeStatisticPairAsInt.push_back(str_to_number<int>(element));
    }
    singleGradeStatisticPairs.push_back(singleGradeStatisticPairAsInt);
}
```

Which works correctly. Printing out the result with

```
std::cout << "singleGradeStatisticPairs:" << fplus::show(singleGradeStatisticPairs) << std::endl;
```

leads to the correct printout `singleGradeStatisticPairs:[[10, 1], [20, 2], [30, 3]]`.

Now I attempted to implement this in functional style as

```
auto singleGradeStatisticPairs = fplus::transform(
    fplus::fwd::transform(str_to_number<int>), singleGradeStatisticPairsAsStr);
```

This gives me a compiler error:

```
E0304:  no instance of function template "fplus::transform" matches the argument list
```

How can I correctly solve the problem, using functional programming?
The above pattern worked just fine for squaring ints in a vector of vector of ints:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> xxs = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} };
auto yys = fplus::transform(fplus::fwd::transform(fplus::square<int>), xxs);
std::cout << "yys:" << fplus::show(yys) << std::endl;
```

compiled without error and gave the correct printout

```
yys:[[1, 4, 9], [16, 25, 36]]
```

I don't see why my approach for the previous problem should be different. For clarity here is the code for the squaring and converting functions, respectively:

```
// API search type: square : a -> a
// fwd bind count: 0
// Returns the square (x*x) of a value x.
template <typename X>
X square(X x)
{
    return x * x;
}
```

from https://github.com/Dobiasd/FunctionalPlus/blob/781172829659301f15f219fc569ff4add3880c83/include/fplus/numeric.hpp

and my own code

```
template <typename T>
T str_to_number(std::string& aString) {
    T number;
    std::stringstream(aString) >> number;
    return number;
}
```

Update: I redefined my definition of `str_to_number`, using a call by value, so the function header is `T str_to_number(std::string aString)`. Now the conversion works just fine, using the functional approach - apparently call by ref. vs. call by value is the problem here, instead of the functional progamming.

Is there a way where I could use references for the strings here?

Comment: Please update your question instead of putting it into a comment.

Comment: @cigien Thanks for the advise, I moved the update into the question.

Comment: My guess is `fwd::transform` needs a function that that doesn't bind a reference to its arguments. Can you post the entire error you get? In particular, the candidates the compiler considered?